# How to get more precise coordinates from Marker.getPosition() in GoogleMaps v2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a `GoogleMap` in which i've implemented `OnMapLongClickListener`.

When the user carries out this action, i record her coordinates using the `LatLng` argument from the overridden method and display a `Marker` at this point.  This `LatLng` provides me with very high-accuracy coordinates (up to 13 places after the decimal).

I've also implemented `OnMarkerDragListener` and when the user finishes dragging the `Marker`, i replace the initial coordinates with the new coordinates supplied by `Marker.getPosition()`.

The problem I'm facing is that the coordinates from this call are much less precise than the initial coordinates and only return to 6 places after the decimal.

How can I return coordinates after a Marker drag that are highly precise like the initial coordinates I get from the `OnMapLongClick`?

Comment: Do you need that level of precision? Even with six decimal places you have precision of up to 11 centimeters. 13 decimal places would be [half the size of an atom](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude).

Comment: why do you need such fine precision. anything beyond 6 decimal places is extremely useless because it is so small

Comment: You could save the OnMapLongLickListener position in your shared preferences and load it instead of the Marker.getPosition() LatLng coordinates, cause I am gonna make an assumption that marker limits precision somewhere. But again, I think they limit it to 6 decimal places because anything after that shouldn't really be noticeable. I may be wrong but I think 6 decimal places will get you to within ~50cm of your position.

Comment: you're all correct. my bad.  this was being caused by another bug. i mistakenly assumed was due to this.  @RogueBaneling thanks for the link